# White Blank Screen on iOS, XCode 9.2, Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am facing an Apple bug (I think) that when I tap tabs of UITabBar or the item of UITableView I get white blank screen.

This issue not occurs every time. Since I do not think so It is bug of me.

Have you faced this kind of issue?

Is it possible to solve this?

I talked to Apple while App is being reviewed, they also admit it may be bug of theirs. But it is annoying.

What we should do?

[image: Storyboard View]

Comment: Apologize: I don't see any relationship between `tabs of UITabBar` and the `item of UITableView`, might you give more details?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini Both tapping the tabs of UITabBar or item of UITableView result in white blank screen.

Comment: might you share us the code?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini actually there is no specific code, it is on storyboard

Comment: Can you share an image of your storyboard?

Comment: @Daniel I have added